# Determine whether the following improper integral converges or not

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

***Integral Question:***

I have the following question:

> By given the following improper integral: $$I=\int _{1}^{\infty }\left( x^{k} \cdot \ln\left( x^{k} -1\right) -kx^{k}\ln( x)\right) dx$$ determine whether the integral converges or diverges.

---

***My attempt:***

$Solution.$
We shall simplify the integral by "$\ln$" identities.

Therefore,
\begin{gather*}
\int _{1}^{\infty } x^{k} \cdot \ln\left( x^{k} -1\right) -kx^{k}\ln( x)dx = \int _{1}^{\infty } x^{k}\left(\ln\left( x^{k} -1\right) -k\ln x\right)dx\\
\\
\underbrace{=}_{ \begin{array}{l}
by:\
y\ln x\ =\ \ln x^{y}
\end{array}} \int _{1}^{\infty } x^{k}\left(\ln\left( x^{k} -1\right) -\ln\left( x^{k}\right)\right)dx\\
\\
\underbrace{=}_{ \begin{array}{l}
 by: \
\ln( x) \ -\ \ln( y) \ =\ \ln\left(\frac{x}{y}\right) 
\end{array}} \int _{1}^{\infty } x^{k}\left(\ln\left(\frac{x^{k} -1}{x^{k}}\right)\right) dx \\\\= \int _{1}^{\infty }x^{k}\ln\left( 1-\frac{1}{x^{k}}\right)dx
\end{gather*}

Now we examine whether the equivalent integral converges.
Hence, we will apply the following theorem:

> ***Theorem:*** if $f(x) \xrightarrow[x\rightarrow \infty ]{} L\neq 0$, then: $\int_{a}^{\infty}f(x)$ diverges.

Therefore, we examine two cases for $k$:

**1.** When $k>0$ we have:
$$ \begin{array}{l}
\lim _{x\rightarrow \infty } x^{k}\ln\left( 1-\frac{1}{x^{k}}\right) =\lim _{x\rightarrow \infty }\frac{\ln\left( 1-\frac{1}{x^{k}}\right)}{\frac{1}{x^{k}}}\underbrace{=}_{ \begin{array}{l}
L'Hôpital\\
\ \ \ \ \ \ \frac{"0"}{0}
\end{array}}\lim _{x\rightarrow \infty }\frac{\frac{-1}{1-\frac{1}{x^{k}}} \cdotp \left(\frac{1}{x^{k}}\right)^{'}}{\left(\frac{1}{x^{k}}\right)^{'}}\\
=\lim _{x\rightarrow \infty }\frac{-1}{1-\frac{1}{x^{k}}} =\frac{-1}{1-0} =-1\neq 0
\end{array}$$
so the integral diverges.

**2.** When $k<0$, by substitution of $k=-n$ when $n>0$:
$$\lim _{x\rightarrow \infty } x^{-n}\ln\left( 1-\frac{1}{x^{-n}}\right) =\lim _{x\rightarrow \infty }\frac{1}{x^{n}}\ln\left( 1-x^{n}\right) =\lim _{x\rightarrow \infty }\frac{\ln\left( 1-x^{n}\right)}{x^{n}}$$
however this contradicts the domain of "$\ln$", which couldn't get negative values inpputed, which implies that $k$ is a non-negative number.

Thus, in total, we have that the improper integral diverges.

---

***Thoughts:*** I am not sure about the second case, in which $k$ is negative because there might be another way to show the limit of the function when $x$ approaches infinite. Therefore, I will be glad for some feedback about the way I have shown. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution seems complete to me.  I don't think there are any issues with rigor.  In fact, we can already see that we must have $k > 0$ for the function as originally defined, since if $k \le 0$ and $x > 1$, then $x^k \le 1$; therefore, $\log (x^k - 1)$ is not real-valued.  One does not need to consider limiting behaviors to exclude the nonpositive case for $k$.

It is also worth noting that the limiting behavior for $k > 0$ must be independent of $k$, since the transformation $u = x^k$ implies that as $x \to \infty$, $u \to \infty$ and so we need only consider the behavior of $$u \log (1 - 1/u)$$ as $u \to \infty$.  This of course is $-1$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! :)